# Trying to pass a foreign key of my model into URL for dynamic routing

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have 3 models, a custom user model (using AbstractUser - User/Brand models) and a Message model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_brand = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_influencer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Brand(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name="brand_info")
    email = models.EmailField()
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipient')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    message_content = models.TextField()
    send_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have a view where I want to load up all the messages associated with a particular Brand, and this page will also have the  attribute (from Brand model) as a dynamic URL parameter.

Here's my current code for views.py:

```
def conversation_view(request, username):
    messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(message__sender=username) | Q(message__recipient=username)).order_by('send_time')
    return render(request, "conversation.html", {
        'messages': messages
        })
```

And here's my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('conversation/<username>/', views.conversation_view, name='conversation_view')
]
```

When I try and load up a page with the appropriate conversation/ URL, I get the following error message: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'username'`

I'm not sure why Django is expecting an int() here? Is it because I'm using sender/recipient from Message model in my view, which are both foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter on the `message__sender`, so then it is expecting a `User` object, or the primary key of a `User` object.

You can however filter with `message__sender__username=username`, the same applies for the `recepient`:

```
def conversation_view(request, username):
    messages = Message.objects.filter(
        Q(message__sender__username=username) |
        Q(message__recipient__username=username)
    ).order_by('send_time')
    return render(request, "conversation.html", {
        'messages': messages
        })
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).